# Create a search filiter textbox on admin page

Tags: magento2, customer, uicomponent, forms

I am using the https://webkul.com/blog/add-ui-select-with-search-filter-admin-form-magento2/ to create a **search filter** but what I was expecting was

[image]

**I am getting is this, No search area.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at line 6:

```
<field name="customer" component="Webkul_Test/js/components/select-customer" sortOrder="20" formElement="select">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>//to add filter in select-ui
        <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>//select multiple or not
        <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> <!-- THIS LINE HERE -->
        <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <required>true</required>
    <validation>
        <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
    </validation>
    <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
    <label translate="true">Select Customer</label>//label to Field
    <dataScope>data.customer</dataScope>//To map
    <componentType>field</componentType>
    <listens>
        <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
    </listens>
</settings>
<formElements>
    <select>
        <settings>
            <options class="Webkul\Test\Ui\Component\Create\Form\Customer\Options"/>
        </settings>
    </select>
</formElements>
```

Can you try putting "false" instead of "true"? I think that is the problem.

Comment: Did no effects.

Comment: Have you ran the commands:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento cache:flush;

Comment: setup upgrade ? yes

Comment: I found the solution here. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188528/magento-2-add-select-box-with-search-filter-option Thank you for help

Comment: Can this be done with php code of addField? Because I cannot use ui_form for some reasons. please guide.