# Magento2 | Add select-box with search/filter option | Auto suggestor

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute

I am try to add a search bar to the product custom dropdown attribute.
I am able to add it using xml and data is also getting saved, but after loading the product again, it is not showing in admin.

Can some please help

I am following this link as well

[Magento 2 Add select-box with search/filter option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188528/magento-2-add-select-box-with-search-filter-option)

Here is my xml code

```
<field name="xxnmi_project">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">XYZ\ImportProjectData\Model\Attribute\Source\Project</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Project</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">xxnmi_project</item>
                    <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="chipsEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                    <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="newOption" xsi:type="string">toggleOptionSelected</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">conditions</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a DataProvider (DataSource) to your component.
The DataProvider has the responsability to take the values from backend and set as a default value to your component.

Take a look at this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_data_source.html

Comment: This will not work as my edit form is not normal one. The attribute is added in product edit form in admin. My attribute value is getting saved but it is not populating